# next-auth error: 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'Adapter | undefined'

Tags: next-auth

I'm following this documentation: https://authjs.dev/reference/adapter/mongodb to use next-auth. This is the relevant code:

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb"

...

export default NextAuth({
    providers,
    adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
})
```

I get the following error, which makes no sense to me:

```
Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'Adapter | undefined'.
  Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'DefaultAdapter & { createVerificationToken: (verificationToken: VerificationToken) => Awaitable<VerificationToken | null | undefined>; useVerificationToken: (params: { ...; }) => Awaitable<...>; }'.
    Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'DefaultAdapter'.
      Types of property 'createUser' are incompatible.
        Type '((user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'.ts(2322)
types.d.ts(106, 5): The expected type comes from property 'adapter' which is declared here on type 'AuthOptions'
(property) AuthOptions.adapter?: Adapter | undefined
You can use the adapter option to pass in your database adapter.

Required: No
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I ran into the same issue today. I was importing MongoDBAdapter from @auth/mongodb-adapter, but actually needed to import from the next-auth adapter.

I ran:

```
npm install @next-auth/mongodb-adapter
```

Then changed my import to:

```
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@next-auth/mongodb-adapter";
```

I have no clue what the actual issue is, just that installing the right adapter and changing the import fixed it for me.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! So the point was that there are two different objects called both "Adapter".

Comment: I was having the same issue with the Dgraph Adapter. This solution works for it as well, just substitute 'mongodb' for 'dgraph' and you're good to go. I imagine this is the case for the other adapters as well.

Comment: This migration to `@auth` vs `@next-auth` is very frustrating - half the documentation has disappeared for v4 of NextAuth.js and can only be found for Auth.js, but the Auth.js documentation doesn't consistently work for NextAuth.js.

Comment: I have done those, but the problem is still there, until I did the following: <code>adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise) as Adapter,</code> .  I am using "mongodb": "^6.3.0",  "@auth/mongodb-adapter": "^2.0.10",

Answer (score 20):

I got the same type error with `@auth/firebase-adapter`.

```
ype error: Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'Adapter | undefined'.
  Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'DefaultAdapter & { createVerificationToken: (verificationToken: VerificationToken) => Awaitable<VerificationToken | null | undefined>; useVerificationToken: (params: { ...; }) => Awaitable<...>; }'.
    Type 'Adapter' is not assignable to type 'DefaultAdapter'.
      Types of property 'createUser' are incompatible.
        Type '((user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>) | undefined' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '(user: Omit<AdapterUser, "id">) => Awaitable<AdapterUser>'
```

First, import type `Adapter` from `next-auth/adapters`.

```
import type { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
```

and change NextAuthOptions.

```
import type { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {,
  adapter: FirestoreAdapter(firestore) as Adapter,
  ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, stranger, for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was working with Redis/upstash adapter, and had the same issue.

```
import { UpstashRedisAdapter } from '@next-auth/upstash-redis-adapter'
```

In Auth.js they have been using this

```
import { UpstashRedisAdapter } from "@auth/upstash-redis-adapter";
```

But with the Next 13.3 updates, this has been an issue

Comment: And what exactly fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that this has become a common issue on this transition as NextAuth adapter doc links ref the AuthJS adapter docs as "the up-to-date documentation". Same issue occurred for me with the Supabase adapter where the linked docs state to install:

```
npm install @supabase/supabase-js @auth/supabase-adapter
```

Error was cleared by editing the import statement from `@auth/supabase-adapter` to `@next-auth/supabase-adapter` and updating my dependencies accordingly.

In case it helps anyone, there were actually no Typing issues for me while dev'ing on a fedora os and only popped up on my windows laptop running ubuntu on wsl/2. Don't have the time to diagnose the why, maybe its a windows thing,  but feel free to chime in with knowledge =)

Answer (score 0):

For those who got the same problem with any adapters, such as PrismaAdapter, MongoDBAdapter, Supabase Adapter, just cast it as Adapter, like this:
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import { MongoDBAdapter } from "@auth/mongodb-adapter"
import clientPromise from "../../../lib/mongodb"
import { Adapter } from "next-auth/adapters";
...

export default NextAuth({
providers,
adapter: AnyDBAdapter(clientPromise) as Adapter,
})

This maybe a bug from next-auth.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will solve:

take it:

```
adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise),
```

leave it like this::

```
adapter: MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise) as Adapter,
```

Answer (score 0):

try this instead:

```
import { Adapter } from 'next-auth/adapters'
... 
... 
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = { 
adapter: <Adapter>MongoDBAdapter(clientPromise), 
...
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, to fix it, I changed the import information

before

```
  import {PrismaAdapter} from '@auth/prisma-adapter'

  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma)
```

after

```
  import {PrismaAdapter} from '@next-auth/prisma-adapter';

  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).